Is Bert truly a traded breeder from Vault 32, as described on the Amazon page for the Fallout TV series, or was it Steph that was traded?
In the 2024 Fallout TV series on Amazon Prime Video, I stumbled upon a curious detail about Steph Harper and her husband, Bert. On Amazon's page for the show, if you navigate to Explore → Vault Dwellers → Steph Harper, you’ll find that she’s described as a “native resident of Vault 33” and is “married to Bert, a breeder from Vault 32.” The page suggests that Bert was exchanged for some of Vault 33’s agricultural and mechanical resources.


Steph Harper
A native resident of Vault 33, Steph is Lucy’s best friend. She is married to Bert, a breeder from Vault 32 who was traded for some of Vault 33’s agricultural and mechanical resources. They are currently expecting their first child, but that doesn’t stop Steph from taking part in the Young Piker’s Association or any of her other Vault duties.

As the season unfolds, we discover (spoiler alert!) that Steph Harper is actually

 from Vault 31, not 33.

This discrepancy on the Amazon page seems intentional, likely to keep us from guessing the plot twist.
Here’s where it gets more confusing: if Steph was the one who was traded

 from Vault 31,

then her spouse should be a Vault 33 native. Yet, a scene shows Lucy signing her wedding dress, with Steph Harper’s signature above hers. This implies the dress belonged to Vault 33 and Steph resided there before her marriage—ergo, she wasn't the one that was traded, seemingly contradicting the fact that she was

 traded from Vault 31.


These pieces of information seem to contradict each other when piecing together Bert’s and Steph's backstories. What’s the real story with Bert and Steph? Is Bert the breeder who was traded, or was it Steph? Is it Vault 32 or Vault 33 that is Bert's original home?

We know of two other individuals similar to Steph who are in Vault 33, who we find out about in a later episode. It is implied that this source is the master source and provides the prime breeding material while v32 and 33 provide the other half of the equation. The 'trade' from the other source is part of the lie told to 32 and 33

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/122441/vault-32-residents-and-bert
